# Windows desktop .exe flutter release file does not start

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am following the getting started tutorial from https://docs.flutter.dev. I installed Flutter v3.7.8, configured Android Studio 2022.1.1 and created the first app. Everything went fine except for the executable version of windows located at \build\windows\runner\Release that that doesn't open the app, but it can be found in the background tasks.

Flutter doctor says that everything is ok. I tried "flutter clean" before running "flutter run --release", creating the project multiple times and using VS Code instead of Android Studio with the same result. Android debug/release and Windows debug versions work fine, but the .exe file generated by the windows release build doesn't. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.